# Scanning 2 chars in one line

Tags: c, scanf

I am new to C and I am trying to scan two char variables in one line.

I used #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS because I have to.
This is the piece of code that annoys me: `scanf_s("%c-%c", &x,1, &y,1);`

When inputting 2 chars, it looks something like this --->  e-f or a-b
Also, I need to lose `scanf_s` and make it into `scanf` only.

Another thing that is kinda weird to me is that after I input two chars and do actions later, I reset values of x and y to 0 and need to input them again. However, when I type them in, I get completely different values.

Here is the whole code that I wrote so far. Task: input 2 letters and print them in order specified in input e.g. a-c --> ABC or c-a --> cba

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 100

int main(){

    char niz[MAX];

    char kraj[MAX] = {0};

    int razlika;//difference 

    char x, y;
    int i;
    char trenutniznak; //current character
    int stoppolje=0;//stop field
    int temp = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        scanf_s("%c-%c", &x,1, &y,1);
    

        if (x == '.' || y == '.')
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (y > x)//od pocetka do kraja 
        {              //(from start to end )
            razlika = y - x + 1;
            
            for (i = stoppolje+1, trenutniznak=x; i <= razlika; i++, trenutniznak++)
            {
                niz[i] = trenutniznak;
                temp = i;
            }
            stoppolje = temp; // polje na kojem je zadnji znak
                              //(the field where the last character is )
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
            razlika = 0;
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("\n");
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `scanf`.  http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: Don't do `while(1)`.  Check the value returned by `scanf` with `while( scanf(" %c-%c", &x, &y) == 2 ){ ...`. Note the leading whitespace in the format string and understand what it does.

Comment: I am first year of college and for our online code grader we have to use scanf. :/

Comment: you're not printing anything out, how do you even know if it's working or not?

Comment: The equivalent of `scanf_s("%c-%c", &x, 1, &y, 1);` would be `scanf("%c-%c", &x, &y);` but note the addition of a space in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70098901/scanning-2-chars-in-one-line#comment123915521_70098901).

Comment: Be aware that by forcing you to use `scanf`, your instructor is forcing you to do the equivalent of learning how to ride a bicycle with square training wheels.  Now in fact, once you learn C well, you will never use `scanf` again.  It's useful, at best, for very simple input.  What you're trying to do here is not "very simple", and is more or less a complete waste of time.  So do what you must to placate your myopic instructor, but don't imagine you're learning anything useful.

Comment: @RenatoRak "looks something like this ---> e-f or a-b" --> Did you also type a <Enter> aka `'\n'`?  That is a character too.

Comment: If `scanf()` is not necessary, consider using fgets(), then the resulting string array, say `char buf[4];` the the array elements  `buf[0]`, `buf[1]` and `buf[2]` will contain for example 'a', '-' and 'c'.  (`buf[3]` will contain `nul` character.)  These are just numeric values that happen to be within the ASCII character range, but can also be logically manipulated as numbers, eg `if(buf[0] > buf[2])(//do something)`

Comment: You are using a primarily C++ compiler to compile C code; despite it's foreboding name, `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` is entirely appropriate, and pushes the compiler to accept C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to understand and then implement in your code

```
char c;
scanf(" %c",&c); // a whitespace character in scanf() would ignore any number of whitespace characters left in the input stream
printf("%c",c);
```

you can go through **%c** conversion specifier

Answer (score 0):

> Scanning 2 chars in one line

Simplify.  Use `fgets()` to read a *line* of user input and convert that into a *string*.

Avoid `scanf()`.  It does not well read a *line* and is difficult to use when input is unexpected.

```
char buf[80];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
```

Now scan/parse the string into the two characters.  Look for bad input.

```
  char extra;
  if (sscanf(buf, "%c-%c %c", &x, &y, &extra)  != 2) {
    fprintf(stderr, "invalid input <%s>\n", buf);
  } else {
    // Use x, y in some fashion
    printf("Good input <%c> <%c>\n", x, y);
  }
}
```

---

Sneak: If you *must* use `scanf()`, add a `scanf("");` before the `fgets()` to *use* `scanf()`.  It will not read anything.

Answer (score 0):

> *"Task: input 2 letters and print them in order specified in input e.g. a-c --> ABC or c-a --> cba"*

If `scanf()` is not necessary, consider using `fgets()`, then the resulting string array, say `char buf[4] = {0};` the the array elements `buf[0]`, `buf[1]` and `buf[2]` will contain for example `'a'`, `'-'` and `'c'`. (`buf[3]` will contain `\0` character.) These are just numeric values that happen to be within the ASCII character range, but can also be logically manipulated as numbers, so just output the sequence of numbers using a format specifier that will guarantee they appear as ASCII:

```
int main(void)
{

    char buf[4] = {0};
    int c = 0;
    printf("Enter maximum of three characters: eg 'a-d'\n(or ctrl-c to exit.)\n");
    while(fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin))
    {
        //test input
        if((buf[0] < 'a') || (buf[0] > 'Z') || 
           (buf[2] < 'a') || (buf[2] > 'Z') || 
           (buf[1] != '-')
          )
        {
            printf("Invalid input.  Try again\n(or hit ctrl-c to exit.");
        }
        else
        {
            buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = 0;//remove newline
            if(buf[0] > buf[2])
            {
               for(char i = buf[0];i >= buf[2];i--)
               {
                   printf("%c", i);
               } 
               printf("\n");           
           }
           else if ((buf[0] < buf[2]))
           {
               for(char i = buf[0];i<= buf[2];i++)
               {
                   printf("%c", toupper(i));//note UPPER CASE as specified
               }
               printf("\n");
           }
           memset(buf, 0, sizeof buf);//reset buffer for next iteration.
           while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);//clear \n from stdin
           printf("\nEnter maximum of three characters: eg 'a-d'\n(or ctrl-c to exit.)\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed somehow to do it, thank you everyone for answering my question :)

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define MAX 1000

int main()
{
    char niz[MAX];
    char kraj[MAX] = {0};
    int razlika;
    char x, y;
    int i;
    char trenutniznak; 
    int stoppolje=-1;
    int temp = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        scanf_s(" %c-%c", &x,1, &y,1);
    
        
        if (x == '.' || y == '.')
        {
            for (i = 0; i <= stoppolje; i++)
            {
                printf("%c", niz[i]);
            }
            return 0;
        }
        else if(x == '_' || y == '_')
        {
            niz[stoppolje + 1] = ' ';
            stoppolje += 1;
        }
        else if (y > x)//od pocetka do kraja
        {
            razlika = y - x + 1;
            trenutniznak = x;
            for (i = stoppolje+1, trenutniznak; i < razlika+stoppolje+1; i++, trenutniznak++)
            {
                niz[i] = trenutniznak;
                temp = i;
            }
            stoppolje = temp; // polje na kojem je zadnji znak
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
            razlika = 0;
        }//ako idemo po redosljedu abecednom
        else if(x>y)
        {
            razlika = x-y + 1;
            trenutniznak = x;
            for (i = stoppolje+1, trenutniznak; i < razlika + stoppolje + 1; i++, trenutniznak--)
            {
                niz[i] = trenutniznak;
                temp = i;
            }
            stoppolje = temp;
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
            razlika = 0;
        }
        else if (x == y)
        {
            razlika = 0;
            trenutniznak = x;
            for (i = stoppolje + 1, trenutniznak; i < razlika + stoppolje + 2; i++, trenutniznak++)
            {
                niz[i] = trenutniznak;
                temp = i;
            }
            stoppolje = temp;
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
            razlika = 0;
        }
         
    }
}
```

Comment: You really don't want to do this.  How does this program respond when run as `echo "a-z" | ./a.out`?  (Answer: not well).  You really, really want to structure the loop as `while( scanf(...) == 2 )`.